# Regex string not matching after replacing multiple spaces in strings

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to match two strings which are essentially same but may have a different number of spaces between them.

```
a = 'Lorem.  Ipsum'
b = 'Lorem. Ipsum'
```

I removed the extra spaces between them and added escape characters before matching.

```
a = re.sub(r'\s+', r' ', a)
a = re.escape(a)

b = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', b)
b = re.escape(b)
```

However, the strings do not match on the following code

```
print(bool(re.match(b, a)))

>False
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do not `re.escape()`, or `re.escape` the `b` again. However, I suspect you wanted `print(a==b)`, to just see if `a` and `b` are equal. See https://ideone.com/W2Fv6O

Comment: Btw, your title is wrong, it is not the problem that you removed extra spaces. The problem is that you used a fixed/literal string as a regex pattern to match the same string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I reduced the actual problem to this form. In the actual problem, I would try to check if string b is in a. As for your solution, "Do not re.escape(), or re.escape the b again." and your solution in the link contradict. `print(bool(re.match(re.escape(b), a)))`

Comment: No, there is no contradiction. `re.escape` introduces backslashes into the string, the backslash before a space stops it from matching. `Lorem. Ipsum` regex will match `Lorem. Ipsum` string, so either do not `re.escape` anything, or `re.escape` `b` when used as a regex pattern.

Comment: Also, to check if `a` contains `b`, you just need `if b in a`. So, `a = 'Lorem.  Ipsum';
b = 'Lorem. Ipsum'; print( re.sub(r'\s+', r' ', b) in re.sub(r'\s+', r' ', a) )`. In regex world, you need to use `re.search` since `re.match` only looks for a match at the string start.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
a = 'Lorem.  Ipsum'
b = 'Lorem. Ipsum'

a=a.replace(" ",'')
b=b.replace(" ",'')
print(bool(re.match(b, a)))
```

The response was True

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 'Lorem.  Ipsum'
b = 'Lorem. Ipsum'

a = re.sub(r'\s+', r' ', a) # a = Lorem. Ipsum
a = re.escape(a) # a = Lorem\\.\\ Ipsum

b = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', b) # b = Lorem. Ipsum
b = re.escape(b) # b = Lorem\\.\\ Ipsum

bool(re.match(b, a)) # False
```

Last line tries to match the string `a` by RegEx pattern `b`. Compiled pattern `b` will match string `Lorem. Ipsum`, but `a` is having a value of `"Lorem\\.\\ Ipsum"`. That's why it's getting no match and returns `False`.

To make this work, you don't need to escape string `a`, because it's not a regular expression.

Also, I would recommend avoid using regex for checking strings for equality, because it will perform worse than `==` does. If you're using `bool(re.match(b, a))` notation to check whether `a` starts with `b` (this is how `re.match` [works](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match)), consider using [startswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) function.